# How to make exe file from Reactjs and a nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, exe

I am using reactjs for frontend and nodejs for backend. Now I want or have to convert this app or project in exe file. Is some way I can package this into a .exe?
Please suggest me if this possible or not. If possible please help me for this.

Comment: You may be looking for Electron.

Comment: @SLaks can you explain more because I am in new this.

Comment: [Here](https://electronjs.org)

Comment: Why would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Electron](http://electron.atom.io) has already been [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064318/how-to-make-exe-file-from-reactjs-and-a-nodejs-app#comment98768653_56064318) by @SLaks.

Another way to package a JavaScript app as an executable is using NW.js. Docs [here](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Package%20and%20Distribute/#package-option-2-zip-file).

Simply, compress your `.js` sources (you'll need to write some NW boilerplate, see the [docs](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/)) into a `.zip`, and concatenate that with `nw.exe`:

```
copy /b nw.exe+your.zip your.exe
```

Then you get `your.exe`, an executable version of your app.